# Hide columns when using to_excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have two DataFrames, each with multiple columns.

I am saving these to Excel in different sheets.

For the `dir_tree_df` dataframe, I would like the first 3 sheets hidden.
For the `table_of_contents_df` dataframe, I would like the first column hidden.

Is this possible? I've seen a possible solution here, but unsure how to implement it in my code

[Is it possible to create an excel file with hidden columns in Python using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619593/is-it-possible-to-create-an-excel-file-with-hidden-columns-in-python-using-panda)

**My Code**

```
 with pd.ExcelWriter(target_directory + 'output_test.xlsx') as writer:  
        table_of_contents_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Contents', index = False)
        dir_tree_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index = False)
```

Answer (score 5):

Think I solved it. The docs helped:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(target_directory + 'output_test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter') as writer:  
            table_of_contents_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Contents', index = False)
            dir_tree_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index = False)
    
            worksheet = writer.sheets['Contents']
            worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, None, {'hidden': 1})
    
            worksheet = writer.sheets['Data']
            worksheet.set_column('A:C', None, None, {'hidden': 1})
```